# Why can't Java create this file on my Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: java, file-io, ubuntu-12.04, ioexception, ext4

I have the following **existing** directory structure on my file system (Ubuntu 12.04 desktop using ext4):

```
/
    home/
        myuser/
            .myapp/
                logs/
                    myapp.log
                data/
                lib/
```

...and the following Java code:

```
try {
    // If no such file exists, create it and write zero (0) to it.
    if(!myFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("myFile is: " + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
        myFile.createNewFile();
        myFileWriter.write("0"); // Configured to write to myFile
    }
} catch(IOException ioExc) {
    logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ioExc));
    throw new RuntimeException(ioExc);
}
```

...that is throwing the following exception:

```
myFile is: /home/myuser/.myapp/data/replay/Loader-0-replay.log
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at net.myuser.myapp.tools.myapp.Loader.<init>(Loader.java:69)
    at net.myuser.myapp.tools.myapp.MyAppTool.loadWords(MyAppTool.java:125)
    at net.myuser.myapp.tools.myapp.MyAppTool.run(MyAppTool.java:65)
    at net.myuser.myapp.tools.myapp.MyAppTool.main(MyAppTool.java:41)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:900)
    at net.myuser.myapp.tools.myapp.Loader.<init>(Loader.java:62)
    ... 3 more
```

What is going on here? It says "**No such file or directory**", but isn't that what `createNewFile()` is supposed to do for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227650/java-create-a-file-not-a-folder

Comment: Create the complete directory structure first. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3090789/1296402

Comment: Where do you set the value of `myFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the folder /home/myuser/.myapp/data/replay before you create the file.

You could try something like

```
if (!myFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("myFile is: " + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
    if (!myFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    myFile.createNewFile();
    myFileWriter.write("0"); // Configured to write to myFile
}
```

Check the reference:

- [File.mkdir()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29)
- [File.mkdirs()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

/home/myuser/.myapp/data/**replay**/Loader-0-replay.log

I don't see 'replay' in the directory listing you gave.

Try getting the parent File from myFile and then calling [File.mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).